How to verify textvariable in Entry widget if it's an integer or not
I am doing a ticket booking system for school and I have encountered a problem when I'm trying to verify whether the value entered in an Entry widget is an integer or not. Attached is my program and sorry for the messy format and convention of my program.
# Import the Tkinter module for my GUI
from tkinter import *

# Set constants for the price of each ticket and the maximum amount of tickets that could be bought
ADULT = 15.00
SENIOR_STUDENT = 10.00
CHILD = 5.00

# Set a variable for the maximum amount of tickets. I changed it to a variable from constant because this value will change as the user orders ticket
max_tickets = 100

# Create a class for each ticket type ordered
class Ticket():
    '''Setting the values for the classes'''
    def __init__(self, price, quantity):
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    '''Method for calculating the price of a type of ticket ordered depending on the amount of tickets ordered'''
    def calculate(self):
        if self.quantity < 100 and self.quantity >= 0:
            return self.price * self.quantity
        else:
            return False
    
    
def collect_ticket():
    '''This function is responsible for appending objects to a list that I will use for calculating the total price later on'''
    order_list = []
    order_list.append(Ticket(ADULT, adult_quantity.get()))
    order_list.append(Ticket(CHILD, child_quantity.get()))
    order_list.append(Ticket(SENIOR_STUDENT, senior_student_quantity.get()))
    return order_list

def calculate_total():
    '''This function is responsible for adding up the total price based on the type and the amount of tickets of each type ordered by the user'''
    global max_tickets
    total = int()
    for i in collect_ticket():
        total += i.calculate()
        max_tickets -= i.quantity
    amount.set(max_tickets)
    total_price.set(total)

def validate_values():
    valid = True
    for i in collect_ticket():
        if i.quantity > 100 or i.quantity < 0:
            print("Value must be between 1 and 100.")
            valid = False
    if valid:
        calculate_total()

        


# Initialize a Tk() window and set the title of the window as Ticket Booking System
root = Tk()
root.title("Ticket Booking System")

# Create a Label widget for the Ticket Booking System name at the top of my window
topLabel_lbl1 = Label(root, text = "Ticket Booking System", font = ("Arial", "25", "bold"))
topLabel_lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

# Create a Label widget at the top of my GUI to indicate the amount of tickets available to be ordered
amount = StringVar()
amount.set(max_tickets)
amount_tickets_lbl7 = Label(root,
                            textvariable=amount,
                            font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
amount_tickets_lbl7.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="E")

# Create a Lable widget for the Adult ticket and the price for it
adult_lbl2 = Label(root, text = "Adult $15", font = ("Arial", 15, "bold"))
adult_lbl2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="W", padx = 10)

# Initialize a variable that will be of the int type and set it as a textvariable for my adult_entry1 Entry widget
adult_quantity = IntVar()
adult_quantity.set("")
adult_entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable = adult_quantity, width = 15, font = ("Arial", 10, "bold"))
adult_entry1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="E", padx = 10)

# Create a Label widget for the Senior/Student ticket and the price for it
senior_student_lbl3 = Label(root, text = "Senior/Student $10",font = ("Arial", 15, "bold"))
senior_student_lbl3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky="W", padx = 10)

# Initialize a variable that will be of the int type and set it as a textvariable for my senior_student_entry2 Entry widget
senior_student_quantity = IntVar()
senior_student_quantity.set("")
senior_student_entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable = senior_student_quantity, width = 15, font = ("Arial", 10, "bold"))
senior_student_entry2.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "E", padx = 10)

# Create a Label widget for the Child ticket and the price for it
child_lbl4 = Label(root, text = "Child $5", font = ("Arial", 15, "bold"))
child_lbl4.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "W", padx = 10)

# Initialize a variable that will be of the int type and set it as a textvariable for my child_entry3 Entry widget
child_quantity = IntVar()
child_quantity.set("")
child_entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable = child_quantity, width = 15, font = ("Arial", 10, "bold"))
child_entry3.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "E", padx = 10)

# Create a Label for the total price of the order
total_price_lbl5 = Label(root, text = "Total Price($):", font = ("Arial", 15, "bold"))
total_price_lbl5.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky="W", padx = 10)

# Initialize a variable that will be of the int type and set it as a textvariable for my total_price Label widget
total_price = IntVar()
total_price_lbl6 = Label(root, textvariable = total_price, font = ("Arial", 10,"bold"))
total_price_lbl6.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky="E", padx=10)

# Create a button that will calculate the total price the user needs to pay
calculate_btn = Button(root, text = "Calculate", font = ("Arial", 15, "bold"), command=validate_values)
calculate_btn.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = "W", padx = 8)



root.mainloop()



I tried using an .isnumeric() or .isalpha() method in my program but it didn't work.

"it didn't work" how? Please share what you tried, and what happened.
